# Is there a way to write an expression in SSRS to navigate to a specific subreport in a document map?

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a report in SSRS with multiple sub-reports that the user navigates through from a document map.  One specific sub-report has a text box with an action enabled to allow the user to go to the same report and apply different parameters (specified within the action options).  Is there a way to adjust that action somehow to go to the same sub-report from the document map?  If I enter the main report in the action it takes me to the first report of the document map and if I specify the sub-report in the action then it takes me to the link of the sub-report (so the document map goes away since it is part of the main report).

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! At StackOverflow, we are helping developers to get stronger. However, we won't never let company get rid of them by requesting free jobs on this forum. So in order to distinct yourself from these sharks, show us some effort, pieces of code, some bugs, or other... And then we will help you! Please take the tour and read "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" [help/dont-ask], "What topics can I ask about here?" [help/on-topic] and [mcve]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that is possible. If I understand correctly, when you click the link you would like one of two things to occur....

Either....

1. re-open the main report with the new parameters to pass into the subreport and then automatically set the current bookmark to the subreport in question.

or...

2. Open the subreport but retain a document map from the main report.

Option 1: I don't know of anyway to get SSRS to navigate to a bookmark programmatically (within the confines of at least).

Option 2: You could fake a document map in the subreport to look like your main report but the links would only be able to take you to the main report's first page.

There is a third option but I'm not sure how practical it would be as I don't know anything about your report, but could you not just add a second instance of your subreport with the alternate parameters supplied already. You would end up with two bookmarks, one for each version of the sub report, you could show or hide the report based on your existing textbox 'button/link' I suppose.

There may be other ways to do this that people with more brain power than I have this afternoon can come up with but I can't think of anything at the moment.

Comment: Hi Alan,

Thank you so much for your response!  I ended up using your suggestion of the third option and applied different bookmarks with different copies of the same sub-report and it did exactly what I needed it to.

Thank you!!